# Create table to store multiple addresses in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I need to create table to store Physical address, Billing address and shipping address for customer/distributor. Physical address will be always one for a customer/distributor but billing and shipping addresses can be multiple for a particular customer/distributor. So,

> 1. Should I create one table by defining the address type (1,2,3) with customer id column?
> 2. or Should I create three different table for each address type with customer id column?

which will be the best way to store address for future perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always option 1. Anything involving creating multiple tables which store the same kind of information is de-normalising your data structure.

If there's a many-to-many relationship (e.g. 1 address can be used by many customers, or ` address can be used by one customer but for different types of address, e.g. for billing and for shipping) then you need two tables:

- an Address table to store the actual postal address data
- a link table to store the relationship, containing Customer ID, Address ID and type.

Comment: Thanks! You mean a master data table to store the actual postal address?

Comment: Yes exactly. Because that's a re-usable piece of data, not automatically associated with any individual or organisation directly.

Comment: But we are collecting address from customer in customer profile section and we don't have fixed addresses to maintain the master table. We only have Country and State/Province as master data. So how can we maintain master table? Please help.

Comment: Then you could check if you already have a record of that address (e.g. using the unique factors like building number/name and Zip code / Postcode (depending on the country). In some countries you can actually download a full list of every registered address in the country (usually from the postal authorities or government) and pre-load that into your DB, and then you just ask the user to fill out the postal code, and it suggests a list of possible valid addresses. This can increase your data quality a lot.

Comment: Thank u ADyson for your help.